# Eclipse Code Formatter language level error | Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, intellij-idea

Hi I simply installed Eclipse code formatter for mac and tried to format my java file and it gave the following error:

> NavigationJob.java failed to format with Eclipse code
>   formatter. Probably due to syntax error or wrong configuration file.
>   languageLevel=JDK_1_9

Tried searching across for JDK 1_9 in the system configuration for IntelliJ but could not find one. Help please

Comment: It is resolved from the project settings....

Comment: That is already set to Java 8 in Project Settings. This issue is only happening for Eclipse code formatter, so not able to figure out what its solution is.

Comment: Then check again. https://imgur.com/a/e5Azj

Comment: Wohh. That fixes it. That was the issue. Thanks a ton.